# Java PersistanceContext - null, blazeds remote service

Tags: java, apache-flex, ejb, persistence, blazeds

I am using PersistanceContext to inject EntityManager and its works when I use Java for back-end and front-end(JSF:Managed bean), but now i want to use Flex as front-end. I am using blazeds to connect between Java and Flex. I created simple test service that generates list and this works properly. Problem is when i tried to retrieve this list from my databases it turned out that my EntityManager is not injected by PersistanceContext. What i am doing wrong ?

This is the service class:

```
public class simpleService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="gsitePU")    
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
        try {
            TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class);
            usersList = query.getResultList();
        }
        catch(NoResultException e) {

        }

        return usersList;

    }
}
```

Comment: I bet your injection container isn't initialized. Are you using Spring? If so the easiest solution is to use http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex

Comment: No i don't use Spring. This is maven webapplication project with JSF dependency nothing more. Maybe i should use Spring if there is no other soulution(I am beginner programmer).

Comment: I don't know JSF, but that annotation on EntityManager sure looks like dependency injection. The bottom line is this: out of the box BlazeDS will instantiate `simpleService` "normally" (i.e. outside the injection container), hence `em` will not be injected. You'll either have to find an existing solution for JSF or inject `em` "manually".

Comment: Ok thank you very much for tip i will try to do this using Spring.